# Add some attribute values to WooCommerce variable product title from chosen variation

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm looking for some help getting the WooCommerce variable product title to change based on variations. In this specific case I would like the title to change when a color is selected, like "Productname Black".

Is there any easy snippet to get this to work?

Comment: So you would like to add the color attribute value at the end of the product title each time a color is selected, on single product pages, right? … do you have a live link to your site actually?

Comment: Hi! Yes thats correct. For now the website is not live yet, but maybe i can give you some access or is it any easy way acheiving this?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have added you now, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE** 04-2021 - Successfully tested on WooCommerce 5.1+ *(handle custom product attributes)*

The following code, will add to variable product title the value(s) of the chosen variation from specific defined product attribute(s) *(or all of them optionally too)*:

The code:

```
// Defining product Attributes term names to be displayed on variable product title
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_available_variation_attributes', 10, 3 );
function filter_available_variation_attributes( $data, $product, $variation ){
    // Here define the product attribute(s) slug(s) which values will be added to the product title
    // Or replace the array with 'all' string to display all attribute values
    $attribute_names = array('Custom', 'Color');

    foreach( $data['attributes'] as $attribute => $value ) {
        $attribute      = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attribute);
        $attribute_name = wc_attribute_label($attribute, $variation);

        if ( ( is_array($attribute_names) && in_array($attribute_name, $attribute_names) ) || $attribute_names === 'all' ) {
            $value = taxonomy_exists($attribute) ? get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $attribute )->name : $value;

            $data['for_title'][$attribute_name] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

// Display to variable product title, defined product Attributes term names
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'add_variation_attribute_on_product_title' );
function add_variation_attribute_on_product_title(){
    // Here define the separator string
    $separator = ' - ';
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        var name = '<?php global $product; echo $product->get_name(); ?>';

        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
            var text = '';

            $.each( data.for_title, function( key, value ) {
                text += '<?php echo $separator; ?>' + value;
            });

            $('.product_title').text( name + text );

        }).on('hide_variation', function(event, data) {
            $('.product_title').text( name );
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

#### Displaying all attributes

You can display all variations attributes values for the chosen variation by defining the variable `$attribute_names` to `"all"` so like:

```
$attribute_names = "all";
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works… you will get something like:

[image]

Comment: Hi this does not work for me.
 
Please see link to staging site - https://staging.littlebrandbox.com/product/foligain-5-extra-strength-minoxidil-men/

I tried changing attributes not nothing.

Comment: What if it's in a Shop page which has multiple products and I only to make change respective to the product dropdown?