# Change WooCommerce Product Name to Include Attribute When Attribute Selected

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, shortcode, product-variations

I've referenced the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462265/change-woocommerce-variable-product-title-based-on-variation) which works perfectly!

But I am displaying a product on the homepage using a [woocommerce shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-10) and can't figure out how to adjust so it also applies to the homepage.

I tried adjusting the line that selects only product pages to include the homepage, but it does not work:

```
    // Only single product pages
if( ! is_product() && ! is_home() ) return $title;
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only work on **variable products** that have a **Color** product attribute *(for variations)* and it will append the selected Color attribute label value to the product title.

For your **Home page** you will use WordPress conditional tag `is_front_page()`…
You will have to set also the **Product ID** that you are using in your shortcode.

1) In the Home page I have this shortcode example *(with a variable product ID)*:

```
[product_page id="40"]
```

2) To make it work for both single product pages and the home page (product shortcode) too:

```
add_filter( 'wp_footer','custom_product_title_script' );
function custom_product_title_script(){
    // Only single product pages and home page
    if( ! ( is_product() || is_front_page() ) ) return;

    // HERE Set your home product ID
    $shortcode_product_id = 40; // <=====  =====  =====  HERE your Shortcode Product ID

    $product_id = is_product() ? get_the_id() : $shortcode_product_id;

    // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // Only for variable products
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;

    // Here set your specific product attributes in this array (coma separated):
    $attributes = array('pa_color');
    // The 1st loop for variations IDs
    foreach($product->get_visible_children( ) as $variation_id ) {
        // The 2nd loop for attribute(s)/value
        foreach($product->get_available_variation( $variation_id )['attributes'] as $key => $value_id ){
            $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $key ); // Get the taxonomy of the product attribute
            // Just for defined attributes
            if( in_array( $taxonomy, $attributes) ){
                // Set and structure data in an array( variation ID => product attribute => term name )
                $data[ $variation_id ][$taxonomy] = get_term_by( 'slug', $value_id, $taxonomy )->name;
            }
        }
    } 
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                // variables initialization
                var variationsData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>,
                    productTitle = $('.product_title').text(),
                    color = 'pa_color';
                // function that get the selected variation and change title
                function update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color ){
                    $.each( variationsData, function( index, value ){
                        if( index == $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                            $('.product_title').text(productTitle+' - '+value[color]);
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            $('.product_title').text(productTitle);
                        }
                    });
                }
                // Once all loaded
                setTimeout(function(){
                    update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color );
                }, 300);
                // On live event: select fields
                $('select').blur( function(){
                    update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color );
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

This code goes in any plugin file with a constructor (but not in function.php file).

Tested and works.

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much :)