# Change WooCommerce Product Name Include Color When Attribute Selected

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm looking for someone me help getting the WooCommerce variable product title to change based on color. In this specific case I would like the title to change when a color is selected, like "Product name - Black".

I follow this topic [Change WooCommerce variable product title based on variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462265/change-woocommerce-variable-product-title-based-on-variation?answertab=active#tab-top) but it not work with WooCommerce version 3.9.1

and the code

```
add_filter( 'wp_footer','custom_product_title_script' );
function custom_product_title_script(){
    global $post;

    // Only single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return;

    // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);

    // Only for variable products
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;

    // Here set your specific product attributes in this array (coma separated):
    $attributes = array('pa_color');

    // The 1st loop for variations IDs
    foreach($product->get_visible_children( ) as $variation_id ) {

        // The 2nd loop for attribute(s)/value
        foreach($product->get_available_variation( $variation_id )['attributes'] as $key => $value_id ){
            $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $key ); // Get the taxonomy of the product attribute

            // Just for defined attributes
            if( in_array( $taxonomy, $attributes) ){
                // Set and structure data in an array( variation ID => product attribute => term name )
                $data[ $variation_id ][$taxonomy] = get_term_by( 'slug', $value_id, $taxonomy )->name;
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                // variables initialization
                var variationsData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>,
                    productTitle = $('.product_title').text(),
                    color = 'pa_color';
                console.log(variationsData);

                // function that get the selected variation and change title
                function update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color ){
                    $.each( variationsData, function( index, value ){
                        if( index == $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                            $('.product_title').text(productTitle+' - '+value[color]);
                            console.log('TITLE UPDATED');
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            $('.product_title').text(productTitle);
                        }
                    });
                }

                // Once all loaded
                setTimeout(function(){
                    update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color );
                }, 300);

                // On live event: select fields
                $('select').blur( function(){
                    update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color );
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try new code and it work with new version 3.9.2

```
add_filter( 'wp_footer','custom_product_title_script' );

function custom_product_title_script(){
    global $post;

    // Only single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return;

    // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);

    // Only for variable products
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;

    // Here set your specific product attributes in this array (coma separated):
    $attributes = array('pa_colour');

    // The 1st loop for variations IDs
    foreach( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ) {

        // The 2nd loop for attribute(s)/value
        foreach($product->get_available_variation( $variation_id )['attributes'] as $key => $value_id ){
            $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $key ); // Get the taxonomy of the product attribute

            // Just for defined attributes
            if( in_array( $taxonomy, $attributes) ){
                // Set and structure data in an array( variation ID => product attribute => term name )
                $data[ $variation_id ][$taxonomy] = get_term_by( 'slug', $value_id, $taxonomy )->name;
            }
        }
    }



    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                // variables initialization
                var variationsData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>,
                    productTitle = $('.product_title').text(),
                    color = 'pa_colour';
                console.log(variationsData);

                // function that get the selected variation and change title
                function update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color ){
                    $.each( variationsData, function( index, value ){
                        if( index == $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                            $('.product_title').text(productTitle+' - '+value[color]);
                            console.log('TITLE UPDATED');
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            $('.product_title').text(productTitle);
                        }
                    });
                }

                // Once all loaded
                setTimeout(function(){
                    update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color );
                }, 300);

                // On live event: select fields
                // $('select').blur( function(){
                //     update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color );
                // });

                $('#pa_colour').on('change', function(){
                   // update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color );
                    setTimeout(function(){
                      update_the_title( productTitle, variationsData, color );
                    }, 300);
                });

            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```