# Woocommerce: change product name to include all attributes selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This previous answer is so close to what I need: [Change WooCommerce Product Name Include Color When Attribute Selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60193910/change-woocommerce-product-name-include-color-when-attribute-selected)

However, I have 65 products, and they all have different attributes. Some have up to 5 different attributes.

For example: one product has 'sauce choice' and then 'pan size'; another product has 'side dish choice' and then 'meat or tofu choice', etc., so I can't see how I could code for all of these different attributes.

Is there any way to use a wildcard or something in the code so it will pull the selected attributes and add them to the product name?

Just to be really clear, I would like the end result to be something like:

'Spaghetti tomato sauce 2 lb pan'

- 'Spaghetti' is product name
- 'tomato sauce' is result of attribute 1 choice; and
- '2 lb pan' is result of attribute 2 choice.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/help-with-variation-display-in-cart/

Found this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_true' );
```

Added this to my child theme's functions.php file, and it does exactly what I need it to do.