# Product title change with variation selection wooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this product page using woo-commerce. I want to change title initial when size variation selected. If i select 4 inch then title should start with 4 inch. Anyone please help i try some code but its not working.

Already applied this code [change title of variable woocommerce product based on attribute value selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048996/change-title-of-variable-woocommerce-product-based-on-attribute-value-selection)

http://taroxcompany.com/product/solid-wood-legs/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is small snippet for your case (tested and works):

```
default_pr_title = jQuery(".product_title").html();
jQuery("ul.variable-items-wrapper li").on('click', function() {
  currentsize = jQuery(this).attr('data-value');
  if (currentsize != undefined) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery(".product_title").html(currentsize + ' - ' + default_pr_title);
      }, 400);
  }
});
```

You can put this to your theme's footer area. Don't forget to use script tags if it is needed.

What this snippet does:

- stores default value of your product title
- adds click listener to attribute fields.
- and that listener starts change the product title each time when the size is changed.