# Add multiple attribute values ​to the WooCommerce product variable name from the selected variation. Almost works

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for some help getting the WooCommerce variable product title to change based on variations. In this specific case I would like the title to change when a color is selected, like "Productname Black".

Found the JS code from the page:  ([change title of variable woocommerce product based on attribute value selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048996/change-title-of-variable-woocommerce-product-based-on-attribute-value-selection))

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var title_text = $( '.product-type-variable .product_title' ).text(); // get default title
    function add_variation_txt_to_title() {
        var new_title_text = '';
        $( '.variations select' ).each( function() {
            new_title_text += ' ' + $( this ).find( ':selected' ).val(); // collect all variation selected <options>
        })
        $( '.product-type-variable .product_title' ).text( title_text + new_title_text ); // set new title
    }
    add_variation_txt_to_title(); // call on load
    $( '.variations select' ).change( function() { // call on <select >change 
        add_variation_txt_to_titl();
    })
})
```

This code works, but not completely, this code complements the product name + the variant from the variation, but when you change the product from the variation, it does not change, can the code be finalized?

Is there any easy snippet to get this to work?

p/s This does not work:  ([Product title change with variation selection wooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66295423/product-title-change-with-variation-selection-woocommerce))

Answer (score 0):

Решено: Просто в этом коде не доставили букву Е.
add_variation_txt_to_titl(); but you must add_variation_txt_to_title();

Full code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var title_text = $( '.product-type-variable .product_title' ).text(); // get default title
    function add_variation_txt_to_title() {
        var new_title_text = '';
        $( '.variations select' ).each( function() {
            new_title_text += ' ' + $( this ).find( ':selected' ).val(); // collect all variation selected <options>
        })
        $( '.product-type-variable .product_title' ).text( title_text + new_title_text ); // set new title
    }
    add_variation_txt_to_title(); // call on load
    $( '.variations select' ).change( function() { // call on <select >change 
        add_variation_txt_to_title();
    })
})
</script>
```